# How can one install linux google chrome binary on a Mac?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, selenium-chromedriver, virtualenv

I have a Django app that web-scrapes (using Selenium) that I am trying to deploy to google cloud. I am having issues with opening Chrome driver in the virtual environment on google's servers. I believe they are Linux.

I was able to install the linux version of Chromedriver into the virtual environment but I am getting a "cannot find Chrome binary" error as pictured:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaKLF.jpg

I have done some research and it seems that this is because Google Chrome is not installed in the virtual environment. The links to install Google Chrome online all force me to download macOS versions.

*How can I download Google Chrome (specifically its binary) on my Mac so I can put it in the virtual environment that will be run on linux?*

Answer (score 0):

I think that StackOverflow is not the proper place to ask for this kind of question.

You could try to find your problem in the following [Google Chrome Help page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6315198).

If you don't find the answer in the previous link, you could ask for help in the [Google Chrome Help Community](https://support.google.com/chrome/community/?hl=en&gpf=%23!forum%2Fchrome).